# Switching the default session ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, grub2, gnome, 13.10

When my ubuntu 13.10 boots the screen goes black and has no response. I used to run on gnome fallback and would like to switch back to it but I can't get to the login screen due to the automatic login. My only access to terminal is the root shell prompt and I've tried to turn off the autologin in GDM from there but it restricts me to read-only. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using LightDM and Unity:

Log in at the tty terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. It should look something like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]  
greeter-session=unity-greeter  
user-session=ubuntu  
autologin-user=username
```

To disable autologin, simply delete the line and save the file. You can also change the user-session to `ubuntu-2d`, which should resolve the black screen issue.

### If you are using GDM and GNOME:

Log in at the tty terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf`. It should look something like this:

```
[daemon]
TimedLoginEnable=false
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
TimedLogin=username
AutomaticLogin=username
TimedLoginDelay=30
DefaultSession=gnome
```

To disable autologin, change the `AutomaticLoginEnable` line to `false` and save the file. You can also change the DefaultSession to `gnome-2d`, which should resolve the black screen issue.

Comment: I tried, it tells me no such file exists. I don't think I have lightdm installed

Comment: I added instructions for GDM. Please don't use the `unity` tag on your question if you're using GNOME.

Comment: I have edited the custom.conf but it still boots to a black screen. I used the unity tag because when I update version it changes back to unity as default environment.

Comment: Also if the custom.conf file doesn't have the line that says "default session=gnome" what do I do, it doesn't show that anywhere in the file. @Donarsson

Comment: Try adding the line as `DefaultSession=gnome-2d`. It can't get worse, so it's worth a try.

Comment: Still to no avail, I did the edits but it still goes to a black screen as soon as it passes the ubuntu splash screen. I've done the edits on both lightdm and GDM